# Is it possible to implement a single function on onChange event on the form element and track the event occurred in the particular input element?

Tags: reactjs

This is how I currently handle forms in order to play with the form data.

```
render()
{
    return (
       <form>
          <input type="text" name="username" onChange={event => this.handleUsernameChange(event)} />
          <input type="password" name="password" onChange={event => this.handlePasswordChange(event)} />
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"  onChange={event => this.handleRememberMeChange(event)}> Remember Me
       </form>
    );
}

onUsernameChange(event)
{
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
    ...
}

onPasswordChange(event)
{
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
    ...
}
```

In case of bigger forms containing many elements, writing onElementChange() function on all the elements will get tedious. Is it possible to write a single onChange function on the form element and also grab the event and properties of the element in which the change occurred?

```
<form id="form" onChange={event => this.onFormChange(event)}>
     <input type="text" name="username" />
     <input type="password" name="password" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"> Remember Me
</form>

onFormChange(event)
{
    ...
    this.setState({ ... })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

For that write a common onChange function for all input field and Define name with each input field same as the state variable name, then use `e.target.name` to access the state variable name and update that state variable inside `onChange` function like this:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.onFormChange}/>
    <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onFormChange}/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" onChange={this.onFormChange}/> Remember Me
</form>

onFormChange(e){
    let target = e.target;
    this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.type == 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
    })
}
```

and bind `onFormChange` function inside constructor:

```
this.onFormChange = this.onFormChange.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks. I came across this solution. But is it possible to simply implement this on the form element instead of in each of the form inputs?

`<form onChange={event => this.onFormChange(event)}>`

Comment: i think that is not possible, we need to write it on each field.

Comment: Thanks for the info.